# Read a certain line in a txt file and write the value in a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I need to import a certain value in a certain Excel cell. The value is read from a .txt file.

In example a text file done like so, saved in C:\Values.txt

```
Josh  
Marco  
Andrew  
Carlos  
a56k  
Banana  
85/A
```

I want to be able to make Excel read a certain line in the .txt file (i.e. line 5) and write in `Sheet("Sheet1").cell(6,8)` this value.

The line number can be read from a certain cell value, or via `InputBox` 
i.e. using InputBox: What line do you need? `5`, and `a56k` is written in cell F8. answering `3` in the InputBox, in cell F8 appears `Andrew`.

I haven't found any way to do anything like that so far, only ways to read the whole file and so on.

Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole file (there are thousands of tutorials for that on Google or [duplicate questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba%20read%20text%20file%20)) and [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) it by line break:

```
MyLines = Split(MyFileContent, vbCrLf)
```

Fifth value is line 5 then.

```
MyFifthLine = MyLines(5)
```

---

Alternatively read the file line by line until line 5 is reached. There are also tutorials how to read files line by line.